# PHP Timezone Conversion - Wrong Offset (DST?)

Tags: php, datetime

I'm using PHP 5.6.17, and when I'm converting timezone from UTC to EST, I expect to get a difference of 4 hours, but I get 5 hours diff.
I also tried using EST5EDT timezone, but the result was worse:

> UTC: 2017-05-15 10:00:00 
>   EST: 2017-05-15 05:00:00 
>   EST5EDT: 2017-05-15 01:00:00

** I relied on the [tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Here's the code I used:

```
$tzUTC = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$t = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), $tzUTC);
echo "UTC: " . $t->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";

$tzEST = new DateTimeZone('EST');
$t->setTimezone($tzEST);
echo "EST: " . $t->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";

$tzEST5EDT = new DateTimeZone('EST5EDT');
$t->setTimezone($tzEST5EDT);
echo "EST5EDT: " . $t->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```

**Where are the timezone offsets defined for PHP and how can I change them?**

I tried installing the [PECL timezonedb module](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/correct-php-timezone/) and to add "extension=timezonedb.so" to php.ini, but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance!